# Same python command with arguments for argparse not working in shell script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04. The python script recognizes argparse arguments properly if I run a command line directly in terminal, but the same command doesn't work properly if I write it in a shell script and run it.

The argparse argument that fails to work is `--checkpoint_file`, where the python code checks if the checkpoint file exists and then load the trained model. While running through a shell script, I print the `checkpoint_file` string and it looks right, but it cannot pass the `os.path.isfile` and the model fails to load.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint_dir', default='./checkpoint', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint_file', default='', type=str)
opt = parser.parse_args()

checkpoint_file = os.path.join(opt.checkpoint_dir, opt.checkpoint_file)
print(checkpoint_file) 
assert os.path.isfile(checkpoint_file), \
        "Error: no checkpoint %s found!" % checkpoint_file
checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_file)
```

I wrote the command in a shell script `Run_script.sh` under the folder `script`:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python Code_101.py --batch_size 4 --checkpoint_file Model_name/40_checkpoint.pth.tar
```

and `sh script/Run_script.sh`, the output was:

```
./checkpoint/Model_name/40_checkpoint.pth.tar
AssertionError: Error: no checkpoint ./checkpoint/Model_name/4 found!point.pth.tar
```

But the same command worked properly when I ran it directly in Terminal. What's wrong?

**EDIT**:

If I `cp script/Run_script.sh .` and `sh Run_script.sh`, the same error occurs.

If I use `--checkpoint_dir /home/my_folder/checkpoint`, the same error occurs.

When I train the model without the `--checkpoint_file` argument, the shell script works properly.

Comment: Are you running the command from same location in both cases?

Comment: Have you tried running the script with an absolute checkpoint directory instead of a relative one? E.g. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python Code_101.py --batch_size 4 --checkpoint_file Model_name/40_checkpoint.pth.tar --checkpoint_dir /home/<yourname>/checkpoint`?

Comment: you should cd to checkpoint at first

Comment: Yes, the same location. The shell script is under a folder (I updated my question) but it fails too if I copy the file to the current folder and then run it.
I tried an absolute checkpoint directory but it didn't work.

Comment: The python code is in the current location. If I cd to the checkpoint folder, user absolute path of python code, change `--checkpoint_dir` to `./`, I get the same error.

Comment: A good place to start is `bash -x yourscript`; this will log the exact command it runs to stderr (with a prefix corresponding to `PS4`). If your script is, say, saved with DOS newlines, that'll make it obvious (the last command will be written like `$'found!point.pth.tar\r'`, with the `\r` in it)... and either way, you can compare the output against what you know works when run interactively.

Comment: BTW, just as a matter of general good practice, if you're testing against an interactive interpreter, you probably want to run with `bash`, not `sh` (which is considerably less featureful than the aforementioned interactive interpreter or any of its contemporaries).

Comment: Thank you for your tip! The last argument is `--checkpoint_file $'Model_name/40_checkpoint.pth.tar\r'`. If I run this exact command directly in terminal, I get the same error. How should I fix it in the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shell script is started from a different directory? This would change the result for the `.` in your relative path.

Try converting the `checkpoint_dir` to an absolute path using `os.path.abspath()` before using it. If the error still occurs, it will tell where in the filesystem it's looking for your file.

Most likely, you want to define the default path based on `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`, and not on `.`.

Comment: Yes, the shell script is under a subfolder (I updated my question). However, if I copy the script to the current folder and run it, the same error occurs. I tried `opt.checkpoint = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'checkpoint')` and `checkpoint_file = os.path.join(opt.checkpoint, opt.resume)`, it didn't work. I `print(checkpoint_file)` and it looks right.